# How to split a string and get the last part?

Tags: java, string

I have a string `Saxon Securitie/Logo/horse-logo.jpg_1413458235818 in format "A/B/C"`

I want the result as C by removing "A/B/" from the above string and get a result

```
String C = "horse-logo.jpg_1413458235818"
```

Comment: ? I don't understand your question, could you explain in better detail?

Comment: Use split() function and get the last index split.

Comment: What about "Saxon Securitie/Logo/"

Comment: In addition to what @Jayaraj said, use '/' as you splitter argument

Comment: Is it possible for A, B or C to include `/` ?

Comment: @Joni           http://ideone.com/iyhR8M

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
  String s = "Saxon Securitie/Logo/horse-logo.jpg_1413458235818";
  String c = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String filePath = "Saxon Securitie/Logo/horse-logo.jpg_1413458235818";
String fileName = new File(filePath).getName();
```

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.lastIndexOf` to do that :

```
String path     = "Saxon Securitie/Logo/horse-logo.jpg_1413458235818";
int    index    = path.lastIndexOf("/");
String fileName = index == -1 ? null : path.substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you answer but you could easily use split function in java that you can learn about [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm). and at first split with space then split with `/`

Comment: This is a link-only answer, you should add some precisions.

Comment: @Dici I know, I was editing my answer.